# Postgresql - How do I find compressed fields in a table?

Tags: postgresql, compression

Postgresql uses different storage techniques for field values. If values become large (e.g. are long texts), Postgresql will eventually apply compression and/or TOAST the values.

How do I find out which fields in a table are compressed?

(Backgound: I have database that stores tiny BLOBs in a some columns and I want to find out how much of it is compressed - if compression is hardly used, I want to turn it off, so Postgres won't waste CPU cycles on trying)

Comment: Per [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html) all the toastable columns in a table are stored in one TOAST table as rows of chunks. I don't know if there is a way to pull out that data for an individual column. Yo can pull out the overall size with `select relname,  pg_relation_size(reltoastrelid, 'main') from pg_class where relname=<some_table>`.

Comment: Should add that in `psql` you do `\d+ <some_table>` to see what the `Storage` value as relates to section *73.2.1.`* in the `TOAST` link above.  Probably good idea to read that complete section anyway. My guess is you will it best to just leave the setting alone.

Comment: The overall size is not my concern, I already know that. What I need to know is which fields were compressed by Postgres and which were not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in v14, there is the function [pg_column_compression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-admin.html).

```
select pg_column_compression(colname),count(*) from tablename group by 1;
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! 48 compressed vs 23181263 uncompressed gives a strong indication.